# Chrome lets me access files on a server, but both firefox and safari claim they're protected?

Tags: web-server, permissions

I have a webserver where navigating to html or xml pages with Chrome causes no problems, but I get a uname/password security prompt if I try to access the same links from either firefox or safari?  What would cause this situation?

Thanks,
Yarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen when you or someone else saved a username/password combination.

(Also, this should be moved to superuser.com, since the question is about the client, not the server)

Comment: K thanks- if this is the only possibility then you're right, it's a client issue